# Ошибка в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как решить ошибку ? `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Ininvation' not found`
Модель Ininvation, контроллер InivationController, таблица Ininvations
Пытаюсь записать значения в таблицу
Почему он ругается на контроллер ?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Inivation;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InivationController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request){

        $inivation = Ininvation::create($request->all());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас подключена модель `Inivation`, а пытаетесь создать `Ininvation`. Будьте внимательнее.